# aws S3 bucket policies to allow SNS and only one user to write

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting mad with configuring some policies for an S3 bucket,

Basically what I need is a write protected bucket that only a specific user can write to, and there's no way anyone else can (not even me with admin role, being able to change this policy).

I also need that modifications to files in this folder are notified via SNS.

I already have the SNS configured and tested.

and this is the policies json I'm working on:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy16234567654",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt13445614",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketNotification",
        "s3:PutBucketNotification"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::protected-configurations",
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt16323445616",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectTagging",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::protected-configurations/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt163234534",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::15436577732:user/editor"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::protected-configurations/prod/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt16371234523615",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::protected-configurations",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::15436577732:user/editor"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

this policy configuration gives me:

> API response: Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

the reason I'm specifying the `PutBucketNotification` action is to get updates to the files by anyone notified via SNS, via an event notification, but when I set the notification to use my SNS I get:

> Unable to validate the following destination configurations

(but nothing follows)

I'm not sure about the need to specify the first two statements, I'd like to keep it clean if possible, and just specify the

Comment: You should consider the two issues separately, one has nothing do to with the other and the question gets really confusing as a result of that. 1. You want nobody other than one user to write into the bucket. 2. You want SNS notifications from the bucket. What part of this works? If none work then start getting one of them to work instead of both at the same time. E.g. which policy statement does cause the failing api response? E.g. `GetBucketPolicy` does not make sense on `"arn:aws:s3:::protected-configurations/*"`, only on `"arn:aws:s3:::protected-configurations"`.

Comment: Failing destination configs may be a result of the bucket / s3 not being allowed to write into the target topic. It is entirely unrelated to any bucket policy.

Comment: The only thing you actually need are the Deny statements unless you want cross-account access to the bucket. If you are in the same account and your special user e.g. has s3:* it is enough to only have the deny here, any other user cannot putobject in that case but every user with a proper attached policy can e.g. change the notification configuration.

Comment: uhm, ok, then I updated the policy with just `"Sid": "Stmt163234534"` and    `"Sid": "Stmt16371234523615"`, now I need to figure out why the SNS isn't working.

Comment: great, indeed it was an issue with access policy on SNS side, saved all configs successfully. now testing.